# Loop para mostrar todas as noticias

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um backoffice para meu website para poder publicar noticias! Alguém sabe como fazer loop para mostrar cada uma das rows na minha base de dados? Agradecimento a quem ajudar!

Nota: Sou novo no PHP e Mysql

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Ligação
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,"",$dbname);


$querypesquisa= "select * from praticar where titulo=titulo and texto=texto 
 and nome=nome";
$querypesquisa_run = mysqli_query($conn,$querypesquisa);
  ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($querypesquisa_run)>0)
    {
        // Loop vai ter a mesma quantidade que o nº de rows // 
          {
        echo '
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <div>Conteudo</div>
    <p></p>
    <footer>MOSTRAR AQUI A VARIÁVEL DE DATA</footer><footer>Nome</footer>'
         ; }
}
else
{
 echo 'Não existem noticias';
}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: Uma pergunta.. No seu query, eu vi que colocou nome=nome, titulo=titulo.. Mas de onde vem essas variáveis para a pesquisa?

Comment: São os nomes de cada  coluna! Penso que se executar essa query ele vai dar todos os resultados certo? Então serve para verificar se o nº da mesma é maior que 0 porque se não é porque nenhuma noticia foi publicada e se for maior que 0 precisava agora do loop para mostrar cada uma das noticias que sejam publicadas no backoffice (já feito)! Corrija-me se estiver errado por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, ali no seu query, não precisa do nome=nome, titulo=titulo.. Para isso é só aplicável se você quer procurar algum dado específico no banco de dados, exemplo:

```
$nome = "AlmostDone";
$query = "SELECT * FROM praticar WHERE nome = '$nome' ";
```

Na sintaxe exemplo de cima, você está usando o WHERE para mostrar para você somente dados que o nome seja igual a variável $nome (no qual atribuímos o valor de AlmostDone), então basicamente o banco lê assim:

**"SELECIONE tudo DE praticar ONDE nome SEJA IGUAL a AlmostDone"**

Mas no seu caso, não precisa colocar nome=nome, basta colocar:

```
$querypesquisa= "select * from praticar";
```

Pois só isso equivale a sua pesquisa, ele vai listar tudo da sua tabela, AO MENOS que você selecione uma notícia equivalente a uma categoria (por exemplo: só listar noticias envolvendo esporte), mas para isso tem mais um mar de tarefas antes, e como você é iniciante, aconselho a ler mais um pouco sobre o uso de **MYSQL e PHP**.

Um canal bom para isso é o [Celke](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5ClMRHFl8o_MAaO4w7ZYug), tem vídeo aulas didáticas que farão você aumentar seu leque de conhecimento.

Mas vamos para o seu problema, tem inúmeras coisas inválidas no seu código, desde do loop(que se faz com while para buscar dados do banco de dados) e vários itens fora do lugar (desde "`;`" fora de sua posição).

Ajeitei para você o seu código para listar notícias.. Deixei com  porque imagino que o usuário tenha que clicar nela para abrir a notícia.. Mas se você é iniciante, melhor começar com mais calma.. Coisas mais simples e que não envolva tanto jogo de variáveis e ids de um lado para o outro.

Agora, tem diversas maneiras de excluir um registro, vou te passar um mais fácil.. Mas para isso você precisa do bootstrap para esse método (vou mostrar um que aparece um modal de confirmação).

Segue o código abaixo com o botão de exclusão, modal e jquery tudo certinho para você.. Tome cuidado, que o botão já está em operação, cadastre uma notícia teste se quiser testar seu funcionamento:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Ligação
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,"",$dbname);

$querypesquisa= "select * from praticar";

$querypesquisa_run = mysqli_query($conn, $querypesquisa);
  ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <div>Conteudo</div>

    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querypesquisa_run)){
    ?>
    <p>
      <?php echo $row['id'] ?>-
        <a href="#">
        <?php echo $row['nome'] ?>
        </a>
   </p>
    <footer><?php echo $row['data'] ?></footer>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target='#deleta_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>'>
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Apagar</button>

<!-- Modal para deletar o equipamento !-->
        <div class="container">
        <div class="modal fade" id='deleta_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>' role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Você tem certeza que deseja apagar o <?php echo $row['nome'] ?>?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="teste2.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
                       class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">
                        <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Apagar Registro</a>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <?php }; ?>

 </body> 

</html>
```

Agora, repare nesta linha:

```
<a href="teste2.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"..
```

Você precisa criar outro arquivo para fazer a exclusão (caso queira outro nome, coloque ele no href substituindo o **teste2.php** por outro nome que você queira colocar na página de exclusão. (do **?** em diante, ***não apague nada!***)

Segue o **teste2.php**:

```
<?php
// Ligação
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,"",$dbname);

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query_volta = "SELECT * FROM praticar";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query_volta);
$row_volta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$id_volta = $row_volta['id'];

  //Cadastro de equipamentos
  $query_deleta = "DELETE FROM praticar WHERE id=$id";
  $resultado_deleta = mysqli_query($conn, $query_deleta);
  $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows();

  if(mysqli_affected_rows() != 0){
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"Equipamento apagado com sucesso.\")";
    header("Location: index.php");
  }else{
    echo 'Erro ao apagar o registro!';
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Sim o conn está a receber esses valores esqueci de copiar mas sim a ligação a base de dados está correta!

Comment: Já testei era mesmo isto que pretendia! Esclarecendo dúvidas o que faz o mysqli fetch assoc?

Comment: Outra coisa eu tenho a date a ir buscar a hora atual! Mas eu queria que cada artigo fosse buscar a hora atual mas a que foi publicada sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Já consegui da data agora quero criar na parte do backoffice algo para eliminar uma row da base de dados! Caso seja necessário eliminar alguma noticia

Comment: Certo, vou por partes primeiro sobre a sua dúvida sobre o mysqli_fetch_assoc, basicamente é usado com o resultado de mysqli_query. ele cria um array que representa a linha do dado retornado do banco de dados. Você pode ler mais sobre ele e o "irmão" dele o mysqli_fetch_array aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Sobre a exclusão, vou editar a resposta para adicionar um botão de excluir ao lado de cada notícia.. Daí você pode pegar esse botão e colocar onde preferir.

Comment: Amigo mas o botão vai ser noutra página também já conclui o botão!! Agora só preciso que envie mensagem quando é apagado com sucesso e quando não como faço echo num alert de javascript?

Comment: Entendi.. Normal, defina um if para quando ele for excluído com sucesso, se sim coloque: alert ("registro apagado com sucesso"); window.location.href = 'index.php'; E no else do if, coloque outro alert falando que não foi possível excluir.

Comment: Okay muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Certo, eu que agradeço